# webapp unable to access PostgreSQL database over network

Tags: php, postgresql

I am running a little daft here as i have a problem with accessing database over the network.

I have deployed webapp on server A and i want to access database on server B. I have added necessary rules into iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d 'client ip' --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 'client ip' --sport 5432 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I have added necessary permissions into pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             'client ip'/32        trust
hostssl all             all             'client ip'/32        trust
```

I am also able to connect to the database from server A via CLI

```
serverA:/etc/postgresql/9.4/main# psql -h 'server B Ip' -U postgres -d test
psql (9.4.5)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

test=#
```

Yet my webapp when trying to access the database from Server A throws me this error:

```
Message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: 
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "ServerA ip", user "postgres", database "test", SSL on 
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "ServerA ip", user "postgres", database "test", SSL off
```